# getting all item's name,and items count in a listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox, listboxitem

Okey.. here is a code,or something like that.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    noselect = True
    'dim-eli a KS-t(keres/kinalt) aszerint,hogy,mi van select-elve 
    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        ks = "Kínál"
    Else
        ks = "Keres"
    End If

    'count-ol -1-tol a listbox1.items.count-ig(pl 4)


    kód.RichTextBox1.Text = "[hr][img]http://kepfeltoltes.hu/160512/seeadfix_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png[/img][hr][table]" & vbNewLine &
        vbNewLine & "[tr][td][b][color=#7CC576]Név:" & vbNewLine & "[/td][td][b][color=white]" & TextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & "[/td][/tr]" & vbNewLine &
        vbNewLine & "[tr][td][b][color=#7CC576]Elérhetőség:" & vbNewLine & "[/td][td][b][color=white]" & TextBox3.Text & vbNewLine & "[/td][/tr]" & vbNewLine &
        vbNewLine & "[tr][td][b][color=#7CC576]Kínál/Keres:" & vbNewLine & "[/td][td][b][color=white]" & ks & vbNewLine & "[/color][/td][/tr]" & vbNewLine &
    vbNewLine & "[tr][td][b][color=#7CC576]Megnevezés:" & vbNewLine & "[/td][td][b][color=white]" & TextBox4.Text & vbNewLine & "[/td][/tr]" & vbNewLine &
    vbNewLine & "[tr][td][b][color=#7CC576]Képek:"
    noselect = False
    For l_index As Integer = 0 To (ListBox1.Items.Count - 1)
        kód.RichTextBox1.Text += vbNewLine & "[img width=1280 high=720]" & --- & vbNewLine

    Next

    kód.Show()

End Sub
```

So,what i want:
I want to add this text `kód.RichTextBox1.Text += vbNewLine & "[img width=1280 high=720]" & -)` to my `kod.richtextbox` , as many times as `listbox1.items.count` is.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you want to actually put the contents of the listbox into your textbox.  Try it this way:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
  kód.RichTextBox1.AppendText(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString & Environment.NewLine)
Next
```

or with a For Each loop:

```
For Each s As String In ListBox1.Items
  kód.RichTextBox1.AppendText(s & Environment.NewLine)
Next
```